# Include jQuery 1.7 js for nivo slider stops my menu drop down

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

i wish i could get some help for a recent issue i am having while including jquery 1.7.js to run nivo slider ...doing so have my mega menu drop down stop working .....
i tried every possible method and options in nivo slider ..including the no conflict jquery as well but still no go ...
    when i disable the jquery include for nivo slider the mega menu drop down starts working and when i enable it the mega menu stops working.Is there anyone ever faced the same problem or can help me getting up and running my site again...its on localhost ..so cant post the link ! (i am using JA T3 based blank template)
thanks in advance !: )

Answer (score 0):

Both extensions are using JQuery so first thing is first delete the reference to JQuery from the Nivo slider and replace with the following:

```
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
    //If JQuery has not been inserted
    if (!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')) {
          //Insert JQuery from url
          JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery', true);
          $document->addScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
    }
}
```

This is what we have always used to ensure JQuery is only inserted once and that there are no conflicts. I hope this helps you.

Regards